# HP Tilt Pen Eraser

Tags: drivers, hardware, touchscreen, wacom, stylus

I've just bought an HP laptop with the Tilt Pen included.

According to the GIMP documentation, the eraser end of the pen should be recognised as a different input device to the tip of the pen, allowing you to select different tools with each end.  But this doesn't work for me; I always get the same tool at both ends and selecting a different tool with one end applies it with the other end as well.

The touchscreen (using my finger) and the stylus **are** recognised as different input devices and have different tools applied to them.

Is there some configuration I'm missing here, or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to get this working. This only seems to work if the touch panel is recognized as wacom tablet. You can find that out by searching your xorg log.

If it isn't - my problem was solved by adding an entry to the wacom's xorg.conf.

Running ArchLinux though. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  It's unlikely to help, since I'm running the GNOME wayland session, but it still might be a pointer in the right direction.